# Delphi FreeLibrary freezes when using TTask in DLL

Tags: delphi, dll

Here is my code in DLL:

```
procedure TTaskTest;
begin
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      Sleep(300);
    end);
end;
exports TTaskTest;
```

After calling this method in host app, then call `FreeLibrary` will freeze host app. 
After debug , I found that the program freezes at `if TMonitor.Wait(FLock, Timeout) then` in `TLightweightEvent.WaitFor` , but the debugger cannot step into `TMonitor.Wait`.
How to solve?

Comment: Probably you need to cancel all tasks in the `DllProc` when the library is being unloaded. That might be too late though. Maybe you need to export a function to perform that task and require that the host calls it before unloading the library. It's also very possible that this is an issue that has been addressed in a more recent release. We don't know which version of Delphi you use.

Comment: We also don't know how quickly you call FreeLibrary after the call to TTaskTest. I am guessing, though, it is less than 300ms, i.e. while the task is still running? (It is a task, so it won't block the calling thread).

Comment: See [RSP-13742 Problem with ITask, IFuture inside DLL](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13742). You will need to use a separate threadpool inside the dll.

Comment: @LURD you need a login to access that reference.

Comment: @Dsm, No problem if you have a valid license. The report was closed as "works as expected" with a comment: *To prevent this failure using ITask or IFuture from a DLL, the DLL will need to be using its own instance of TThreadPool in place of the default instance of TThreadPool.* There is an overloaded `TTask.Run` that takes a treadpool parameter. I guess you could pass one from the main application as a parameter to `TTaskTest` as well.

Comment: @LURD I have a valid license, thanks - but I still can't get in. Anyway, perhaps you should post as an answer, since it seems a valid solution.

Comment: @Dsm, see [System Dashboard](https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) for login instructions. I will submit an answer as soon as I can verify the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130693/discussion-between-dsm-and-lu-rd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was reported ([RSP-13742 Problem with ITask, IFuture inside DLL](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13742)).

It was closed "Works as Expected" with a remark:

> *To prevent this failure using ITask or IFuture from a DLL, the DLL will need to be using its own instance of TThreadPool in place of the default instance of TThreadPool.*

Here is an example from Embarcadero how to handle it:

```
library TestLib;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Threading;

{$R *.res}

VAR
  tpool: TThreadPool;

procedure TestDelay;
begin
  tpool := TThreadPool.Create;
  try
    TTask.Run(
      procedure begin
        Sleep(300);
      end,
      tpool
    );
  finally
    FreeAndNil(tpool);
  end;
end;

exports
  TestDelay;

begin

end.
```

---

Another way is to create the threadpool when the library is loaded, and add a release procedure, which you call before calling `FreeLibrary`.

```
// In dll 
procedure TestDelay;
begin
  TTask.Run(
    procedure begin
      Sleep(300);
    end,
    tpool
  );
end;

procedure ReleaseThreadPool;
begin
  FreeAndNil(tpool);
end;

exports
  TestDelay,ReleaseThreadPool;

begin
  tpool := TThreadPool.Create;
end.
```